# How can I move the mouse pointer with java awt robot?

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener, awtrobot

I am trying to draw a circle around a point while allowing me to still manually move the cursor. I figured out how to draw the circle around a point but if I bump my mouse a little bit it screws up big time. I know that if I move the mouse a bit while making the circle it won't likely come out as a perfect circle but that's fine. My goal is to be able to drag the mouse around with it constantly trying to make circles around that moving point. Here is the code I have so far (I have tried multiple iterations).

```
int radius = 100;
for (double i = 0; i < (2 * Math.PI) + Math.PI / 6; i = i + Math.PI / 6) {
    PointerInfo pointerA = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point a = pointerA.getLocation();
    int yStart = (int) a.getY();
    int xStart = (int) a.getX();
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove((int) ((xStart) + (radius * Math.cos(i))), (int) ((yStart) + (radius * Math.sin(i))));
    robot.delay(68);
}
```

This is what it looks like when I don't move my cursor at all...

[image]

This is what it looks like when I move my cursor a bit...

[image]

I also know that this will only make one circle but I can't figure out how to run this code when my nativeMousePressed event occurs and then stop it when the nativeMouseReleased event occurs. I tried to run the code above in a method that contains a while loop but that did not work. I assigned a boolean to true when the mouse is clicked and then assigned it to false when the mouse button is released but I think the while loop was working on a different thread or something because none of the code would work besides from the infinite while loop. Needless to say, I removed the while loop, for now, to try and figure out why the circle was not printing right :/

Here is a little edit since I may not have made what I am trying to do clear. I am trying to write code that creates circles while allowing me to move my mouse around the screen (I don't want it to recenter). Now assuming I moved my cursor to the right and the code ran in a while loop instead of only creating 1 circle it should look something like this. (I also need to figure out why all those lines appeared because I even printed the locations which ended up looking nearly the same as when I did not move the mouse).
[image]

Comment: Maybe consider changing the work flow slightly.  Get the point of the mouse before you start, then, based on that state, move the mouse to where you need it to be

Comment: I tried getting the cursor before looping but that did not help the situation. The thing is I want to be able to freely move my cursor around the canvas while I hold down left click and have it draw a circle around the moving cursor. The problem is I cant any of those things to work and I am also not sure why it keeps trying to make a circle around the initial point instead of building off my movements.

Comment: I dont get why there are lines that shoot off into the distance because when I print the locations its where I would expect them to be which makes these random lines that much more confusing.

Comment: *"The thing is I want to be able to freely move my cursor around the canvas"*, well, part of the problem is, moving the mouse will now create a new centre point.  Having the original position recored will allow to move the cursor back to a point relative to the starting position of the circle.

Comment: "A" issue is, while the mouse button is pressed, I'm assuming that the parent canvas will "paint" pixels, but your code never releases the mouse button

Comment: I dont think you understand what I am trying to do. I want the pixels to be continuously painted and I dont need perfect circles I just need to be able to draw circles where ever I move my cursor to. I also dont want it to reset to its original spot because I want it to continue to draw circles. I will update my post with a picture of what I assume it would look like if it was working right.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the 68ms delay in which the user is free to control the mouse. In the ideal case, you would use JNI or JNA to temporarily disable the mouse on an OS level. That however comes with its own challenges, including that you might lock yourself out while testing. Since you are okay with a bit of jitter, there is an easier alternative. Instead of waiting 68ms, you could spam-place the mouse to the desired location, decreasing the time a user has to move the mouse before it gets set again. You can do that as follows:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 68; i++) {
    robot.mouseMove(...);
    robot.delay(1);
}
```

Or if the 68ms has to be somewhat precise:

```java
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 68) {
    robot.mouseMove(...);
    robot.delay(1);
}
```

You can play around with the delay to see what happens. A zero delay might be heavy on the CPU.

Comment: The thing is I also want to incorporate the mouse movements into it. Like I want to be able to move my mouse around on the canvas while its creating a circle. I have a more advanced idea in the future but for now I need to figure out how to keep the delay between each stroke while creating a circle around a point even when I am actively moving the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really basic demonstration.

The "problem" here is, the `MouseMotionListener` can't tell the difference between the `Robot` moving the mouse or the user moving the mouse.  So, if you move the mouse while it's drawing, it will add those points as well (you can see it demonstrated below)

[image: Circles]

One thing I did note was the fact that you never release the mouse button, so it will continue to trigger `mouseDragged` events to the underlying window/canvas even after your loop has completed.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<List<Point>> points = new ArrayList<List<Point>>(25);
        private List<Point> activeList;
        private Robot bot;

        volatile private boolean isRunning = false;

        public TestPane() throws AWTException {
            bot = new Robot();
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!isRunning) {
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("...mousePressed");
                    activeList = new ArrayList<>(25);
                    points.add(activeList);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!isRunning) {
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("...mouseReleased");
                    activeList = null;
                }

            });

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!isRunning) {
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("...mouseDragged");
                    activeList.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!isRunning) {
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("...mouseMoved");
                }

            });

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            am.put("start", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            isRunning = true;
                            drawCircle();
                            isRunning = false;
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "start");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (points.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            for (List<Point> sequence : points) {
                List<Point> copy = new ArrayList<>(sequence);
                Point last = copy.remove(0);
                for (Point next : copy) {
                    g2d.drawLine(last.x, last.y, next.x, next.y);
                    last = next;
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawCircle() {
            int radius = 100;
            PointerInfo pointerA = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point a = pointerA.getLocation();
            bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            int xStart = (int) a.getX();
            int yStart = (int) a.getY();
            bot.delay(5);
            for (double i = 0; i < (2 * Math.PI) + Math.PI / 6; i = i + Math.PI / 6) {
                int xPos = (int) ((xStart) + (radius * Math.cos(i)));
                int yPos = (int) ((yStart) + (radius * Math.sin(i)));
                System.out.println(xPos + "x" + yPos);
                bot.mouseMove(xPos, yPos);
                bot.delay(5);
            }
            bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            bot.delay(5);
            bot.mouseMove(xStart, yStart);
        }

    }

}
```

So, you problem is a little understated in it's context/intent, so it's difficult to really make a suitable suggestion, but remember, you're not dealing with an actual "API" you can inject information into, you're dealing with posting events in the system event queue which are then been consumed by the window which currently has focus

Comment: Well the point was to use a nativeMouseReleased event to stop the loop from making circles but I have not figured that part out yet either. Do you know why those random lines appear because when I print out the locations I dont see an skips like I see on the canvas. Also can you move your mouse while the circle is being drawn? I mean I understand that it cant tell the difference between the two clicks but all I want it to do is to just continue making the circle where my cursor left off instead of making infinitely long lines for no reason.

Comment: *"Do you know why those random lines appear because when I print out the locations I dont see an skips like I see on the canvas"* - As I said, I suspect that they are been generated by the target application and since you are reading the mouse position on each iteration, it would be moving the centre point of the circle from the original/start position.

Comment: One thing you might consider is an outer loop, which picks up the current position of the mouse, compares that with the last known position and make a decision about if should draw anything.  If the mouse hasn't moved a much, do nothing, otherwise, draw a new circle

Comment: That is a good theory but I am not moving my mouse enough for the lines to be from me they just appear from small movements. I am also getting the updated position each time so it can just compound off my movements. I really need it to be able to draw while I move the mouse without those weird lines. I assume some trouble arises from that the circle making that starting radius line maybe its doing that every time? If thats true how would I fix it but even if that is true that wont be the whole reason why those random lines are so long.

Comment: You have to remember, all you're doing is injecting system events into the system event queue, how they get handled by the focused application isn't something you can control

Comment: Yea but I can control the mouse output so if an application is reading something "weird" I need to change the output to get the desired outcome. I do not believe for a second that drawing a circle that builds off a users mouse input is too challenging to do... I bet the issue has to do with how I am drawing the circles but I am not sure how to make a better system to get what I want.

Comment: Based on the code you've supplied (and my modifications), the circle generation workflow itself works fine - something is "moving" the mouse while the button is in the pressed state

Comment: Yes I have said this many times I want to move the mouse cursor around and have it draw circles as it goes. The circles needs to compound on top of my mouse movements but I can tell you for a fact that those random lines shooting out are not from me barely moving the mouse.

Comment: I'm sure - my "guess" is it has something to do with how the target application is handling the mouse movements internally, but I can't say exactly what is going on (I don't know what that target canvas actually is). From my experience with `Robot`, it's very, very, very fickle and very, very, very easy to screw up.  You are subject to so many variables which just don't control

Comment: Yea that's really annoying because all I am doing is just adding a few coordinates to my cursor so it makes no sense at all why random lines shoot off to infinity. I have seen other programs that were able to move while taking user input is there another way to do this then?